# How can I run Skype under an SELinux sandbox?

Tags: audio, security, skype, sandbox, selinux

I would like to run Skype under an SELinux sandbox, to protect my computer. However I get the following error:

usr/bin/skype: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied

How do I fix this?

EDIT: Fixed this problem but now have audio playback problems - how do I fix them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, would help this for you. This manual in Russian, I don't can translate this for English. But I use skype in sandbox. I'm recommend this for you. It work. Thanks!
http://masterpro.ws/forum/28-bezopasnost/4594-skype-v-kletke-selinux-sandbox

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: What @CanadianLuke said - please expand your answer, and perhaps use something like Google Translate to translate at least part of it. Otherwise, consider deleting.